# How to check if variable is assigned with default value runtime in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter

I had to make a filter before acting to check if they are not null, but I want to check only those that do not have a default value from the programmer.

Here is an example.

```
public IActionResult InformativeMessages(string informativeMessagesHeadingId, int page = 1, int quantity = 20)
```

I want to check only if informativeMessagesHeadingId is null. When debugging the application I can access this property, but when I tried to get it with LINQ or with reflection it does not give me access to it.

[image]

So my idea was to miss it if it wasn't null. Is there a way to make this runtime happen?

Comment: If I explicitly set value to 20, it still may look like default, but actually it's set value. You can't distinguish this at runtime

Comment: What is the *actual* question? Checking for the default value of a REST request is a different question from checking the default value of a method parameter. You can't check for the default param value, as the value is actually specified at the call site. In this case, that happens during model binding. A Request's parameters and defaults appear in the Swagger docs though. You can also use Data Annotations to specify defaults and restrictions

Comment: You *can* retrieve a method parameter's default value using Reflection with [ParrameterInfo.DefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.parameterinfo.defaultvalue?view=net-5.0). That's an expensive operation though.

Comment: Can you update this test code completely in the post?